# Returning Retrofit POJO from method

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit

Maybe you can help me. I'm having some problems to return form a method, the POJO generated with retrofit.

I need to return from a class method the pojo generated with retrofit, plus some modificatios to de pojo.

this is the method:

```
public MensajeError iniciarSesion(String usuario,String password)
```

and this is the method implementation:

```
    public MensajeError iniciarSesion(String usuario,String password) {
    Conector apiService =
            restAdapter.create(Conector.class);

    apiService.iniciarSesion(usuario, password, new Callback<MensajeErrorR>() {
        @Override
        public void success(MensajeErrorR mensajeErrorR, Response response) {


        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.v("TAG", "ACA HAY QUE HACER EL MANEJO DEL ERROR");
        }

    });
    //here I need to get the mensajeErrorR pojo and make some modifications, and then return it.

    return mensajeErrorR; //Maybe I will return another class, but with data from de POJO 
}
```

How can I get the mesajeErrorR pojo from the success method? Inside of the success method everything is fine, I'm able to see the mesajeErrorR values without problem, I don't know how to access the data outside this method.

Sorry about my english xD

Thanks!!

Comment: You need to get it back on the main thread, or persist it in such a way that your main thread can see it. Nowadays, I use a bus for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two answers to that:

One, is in your `Connector` interface change the declaration

```
void iniciarSesion(String usuario, String password, Callback<MensajeErrorr> callback);
```

to

```
MensajeError iniciarSession(String usuario, String password
```

then you can write:

```
MensajeError error = iniciarSession(usuario, password);
```

and you have error in your method. That said, this will not work if your `iniciarSesion` method is called on the UI thread - an exception will be thrown, because you're not allowed to make network calls on the main thread.

The second answer is that you can't really access the error object in your method. It is being received by callback, and all you can do is restructure your code so that you modify the error object in `sucess` calback, and call another listener with the modified data.